# Android SDK components were not installed

Tags: java, php, android, sdk

I was trying to download the Android SD kit , during the installation process it showed an error saying

> components not installed -  sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21
>   ,extra-android-m2respository and extra-google-m2respository

Comment: Are you working behind a proxy? Try running as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using windows and Android Studio? If so, try running android studio as Administrator.

Comment: It is running as administrator.